# How I can get the second record from mongodb using WSO2 DSS?

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have connected the MongoDB successfully and now have also accessed the `mongodb` records using `WSO2` `DSS` `tryit` tool.  Here is what I received while accessing the records:

[image: Mongo output with DSS]

As you see I get the output as:

```
 <data>{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "589d96d841a427c4389a38d5"} , "domain" : "yahoo.com" , "emails" : [ { "email" : "fghj"} , { "email" : "dfghjk"}]}</data>
   <data>{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "589d993a41a427c4389a38d8"} , "domain" : "yahoo.com" , "emails" : [ { "email" : "fghj"} , { "email" : "dfghjk"}]}</data>
```

As you see there is `_id` in the output. I intent to remove it. But could not.

The query I placed in WSO2 DSS is like this:

```
collect.find({"domain":#},{"_id":0})
```

Where `collect` is the name of my collect of mongodb.

Here s the json structure that I have placed in the ooutput mapping area on WSO2 DSS:

```
{"entries":{"data":$document}}
```

I do not understand what to do in order to exclude or neglect the `_id` field and get only the domain part as it is in my output window.
Kindly suggest me what I can do to make my work done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally new to WSO2, but we have the same surname ;) so I'll try to help.

I'm not sure you can remove the _id field, but I think the correct way to handle this is to create a proxy service, that runs through the json and returns only the fields that you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Buddy.. But I do not know how this is going to help me in resolving my problem. But never mind Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Sorry this is going to be a case of the blind leading the blind :) but a proxy service is basically another webservice running on WSO2 ESB that calls the data service you've already built.  Follow this article: [link]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-AccessingcontentfromJSONpayloads for how to access the fields you want within the json, then return only those fields in your proxy service

Comment: I ca understand ad... Let me check it